# How do I update all libraries, after Migrating to AndroidX?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, androidx

I've have recently migrated my app to AndroidX, blindly without knowing the ins and outs. As a result every time I run the project, it gives me a load of errors.

I have updated all my Gradle Dependencies and targetSDK to the most recent version code. I have also added the following to gradle.properties:

```
android.useAndroidX=true 
android.enableJetifier=true
```

But this has still made no difference.

Some of the following are examples of errors I am getting:

> error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
>
> error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
>
> error: package RecyclerView does not exist
>
> error: cannot find symbol class FragmentActivity
>
> error: cannot find symbol class CardView
>
> error: cannot find symbol class FragmentPagerAdapter
>
> error: cannot find symbol class DialogFragment

I would just like to know I can get rid of these errors, as it is stopping me from running the project on my mobile device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here you can find the full class mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings).
In your case you have to change the imports:

```
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist
error: package android.support.v7.widget does not exist
```

Packages:

```
package androidx.annotation.*;
package androidx.appcompat.widget.*;
```

Classes:

```
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity    androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
    android.support.v7.widget.CardView         androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter  androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter
    android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDialogFragment androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDialogFragment
    android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView   androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have everything set up correctly in your gradle file. The problem is that there are missing packages that have not yet been converted/migrated to AndroidX. Here's a little trick you can do:

- Go to your app.gradle file and right-click anywhere.
- Select *Refactor* on the menu that pops up.
- In the sub-menu, select *Migrate to AndroidX*
- Sit back and let Android studio migrate all your files.

To learn more, check [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) out.

Answer (score 1):

In the Android Studio menu go to Refactor and select Migrate to AndroidX.
Rest the android studio will automatically do.

Other than this if you still find the error then you will have to manual perform certain task.

1. In the layout find all the old one and replace it like

`android.support.v7.widget.CardView`
with
`androidx.cardview.widget.CardView`

you will find the mapping related information here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/class-mappings

just find the old text by using Ctr+F and copy the replacement text

2. In the app build
   `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'`
   with
   `implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'`

you will find mapping related information here https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings